# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'layout' in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am making a normal login with username and password admin & admin.In login component navigate to layout.But i am getting an error like "core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'layout'".please help me..

app.routing.module.ts

```
import {NgModule}     from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'}

        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

my login.component.ts is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string;
  password:string;

  constructor(

    public authService: AuthenticationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  login(){
    if(this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)){
      this.router.navigate(['/layout']);
    }
  }
}
```

my login.routing.module.ts is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../layout/layout/layout.component';
import { LayoutRoutingModule } from '../layout/layout-routing.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'layout', component: LayoutComponent }




];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: you're navigating to the layout route but haven't defined one.

Comment: The layout route is a child of the login route. Its path is /login/layout.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on what JB Nizet said in your comment, when you have a module that is lazy loaded, the paths inside of that lazy loaded module are relative.  If there is any path before the lazy load, that path is pre-pended to ALL of the paths in the lazy loaded module.

So in this case, here is how your paths map:

path: ''
loaded component: LoginComponent
why: redirects to '/login'.  See login below for more information.

path : '/login'
loaded component: LoginComponent
why: lazy loads the LoginModule, where is matches the path of '' and thus loads the LoginComponent

path: '/login/layout'
loaded component: LayoutComponent
why: lazy loads the LoginModule, where is matches the path of 'layout' and thus loads the LayoutComponent

path: '/layout'
loaded component: NONE
why: as this is not prepended with 'login' it does not lazy load the LoginModule, and as such is just looking in the app.routing, where the only valid paths are '' and '/login'

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes up to me after I try to implement lazy loading.

1. Create SpecificModule.routing.module.ts file

   const routes: Routes = [
     { path: "", component: AComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
     { path: "newmessage", component: BComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], },
     { path: "editmessage/:MessageId/:Mode", component: NewmessageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   ];

   @NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
     exports: [RouterModule]
   })
2. Import SpecificModuleRoutingModule to SpecificModule
3. Add entries for SpecificModuleRouting to AppRoutingModule.

   import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
   import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
   import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/services/auth.guard";

   const routes: Routes = [
     { path: "specificmodule", loadChildren: () => import("./specificmodule/specificmodule.module").then(d => d.SpecificModule), canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   ];

   @NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
     exports: [RouterModule]
   })
   export class AppRoutingModule {}
4. Import SpecificModule to AppModule **[This was missing which caused the issue]**